# <a> tag visited color doesn't change on hosted website, but that works good when I open with live server?

Tags: html, css, frontend, localhost, hosting

My problem is this:  tag visited color doesn't change on hosted website, but that works good when I open with live server. [Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sjRj.png)

What problem is this? Do you know any solution? Is it related with some kinda CSS,hosting or what? Thanks.

Comment: As soon as you locally visit a link it will get a `:visited` color because the browser remembers where you went (locally). When you go to your live server, the browser 'thinks' it's a new server, so the colors are default again. Once you visited a link through the live server, that link too will get the `:visited` color.

Comment: I reviewed my hosted website's page source, but I see that <a> tags don't exist there for some reason. However, I styled <a> in my style.css. I use Hostinger as hosting service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

So, I went and deleted cookies of the website from Firefox settings, then that problem solved. I write this answer for people searching help like me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).